# Why does "cp -Rp ~/foo /Volumes/KINGSTON" give "cp: chflags: /Volumes/KINGSTON/Proj/Proj/Color.h: Invalid argument"

Tags: mac-osx, bash, unix, osx-lion

This is on Mac OS X Lion, and I use the following to back up a project folder

```
cp -Rp ~/foo /Volumes/KINGSTON
```

or

```
cp -a ~/foo /Volumes/KINGSTON
```

The `-p` or `-a` is so that the timestamps of the files are preserved.  (KINGSTON is the USB flash drive, and Get Info says I have permission to read and write on this device).

But it will give many errors such as:

```
cp: chflags: /Volumes/KINGSTON/Proj/Proj/Color.h: Invalid argument
```

Can this be fixed?  thanks.

Comment: https://learning-python.com/cgi/showcode.py?name=mergeall-products/unzipped/docetc/miscnotes/mac-chflags-error22.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What filesystem is your KINGSTON formatted to? If it is FAT32, I would guess the file you have mentioned have some attributes which cannot be set on a file in the FAT32 filesystem. In that case, if all you want to preserve is the timestamp, you may:

1. Switch to use some other command for backup, such as rsync
2. Reformat your KINGSTON flash drive to HFS+
3. Remove the special attributes on that file, and hope it won't happen in the future

Comment: good guess... in fact it happens on the external hard drive using FAT32 as well...

Comment: So after I formatted it to Mac OS Extended (Case Sensitive), the error went away... If it is formatted to ExFAT, the error will still be there